# Laravel - Calling Service Class from Middleware - Class App\Http\Middleware\** does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, exception, service, middleware

So i've got some middleware here:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\ChatLog;
use App\Http\Services;

class LogChat
{
    protected $chatLogService;

    public function __construct(ChatLogService $chatLogService)
    {
        $this->chatLogService = $chatLogService;
    }      

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $chatLog = new ChatLog;
        $chatLog->companyid = '5';
        $chatLog->type = 'REQUEST';
        $chatLog->ipaddress = '1';
        $chatLog->name = 'bob';
        $chatLog->message = 'testmessage';
        $chatLog->action = 'click';
        $chatLog->timeTaken = '1';
        $chatLog->fullLog = 'all the log';

        $this->chatLogService->store($chatLog);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

which calls this service here:

```
namespace App\Http\Services;

use App\ChatLog;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ChatLogService
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\ChatLog $chatLog
     */
    public function store(ChatLog $chatLog)
    {
        $chatLog->save();
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\ChatLog $chatLog
     */
    public function show(ChatLog $chatLog)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

which is injected in here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(ChatLogService::class, function ($app) {
            return new ChatLogService();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following exception: ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Middleware\ChatLogService does not exist

What i want to do is call the "store" method in a nicely abstracted way and i feel this solution is very close - however, I can't seem to get around this error. I'm not sure if it's something simple that i'm missing, or if the approach is fundamentally wrong!

I can't see what's wrong!

Ta :)

Comment: Did you try to run `composer dump-autoload` before trying this?

Comment: i did - but no difference

Comment: Hi! Did you try to add your middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php`?

Comment: yep added this: 'logChat' => \App\Http\Middleware\LogChat::class,

Comment: the middleware runs fine, but it can't find the service that's injected in

Comment: And if you use `use App\Http\Services\ ChatLogService;` instead of just `use App\Http\Services;`?

Comment: that fixes it! thank you